# Fire click event on Leaflet layer using latlng pair

Tags: leaflet, geolocation

I have a button on a leaflet map that when clicked zooms the map to the users current location. This function is working properly.

```
<button type="button" id="locator" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
..
$("#locator").click(function() {
  map.locate({
    setView: true,
    maxZoom: 16
  });
```

Using the lat and long of the found location I would like to emulate a click event on the intersecting polygon layer.  To perform this I use the maps 'locationfound' event to fire a click event at the found location (below).  Nothing happens.

```
map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
  var latlngPoint = new L.LatLng(e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat);
  map.fireEvent('click', {
    latlng: latlngPoint
  });
});
```

The polygon layer has the following click event. 
The layer click event works fine when clicked manually, but does not execute via passing latlng pair.

```
var sections = L.geoJson(randall, {
  style: featureStyle,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});

function onEachFeature(feature, featureLayer) {

  featureLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties.ANUM);

  featureLayer.on('click', function(e) {

    console.log('Layer clicked!', e);
  })
};
```

Heres my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/remmi11/7k6m0xye/11/).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't really want to emulate pointer interactions on Leaflet; what you really want to identify which polygon contains a given point (and the only way of doing that you can think of is to emulate pointer interactions).

If you have a look at the [list of Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins), you'll see a reference to [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) and [Leaflet.CheapLayerAt](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.CheapLayerAt). Those should work for your case.

You can of course run your own point-in-polygon geoprocessing via [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) or even through WCS.

Also note that the caveats of CheapLayerAt highlight a problem that you would have with your approach of emulating pointer interactions: if the geolocation results are outside of the visible map area, the behaviour would be strange. Vector features in Leaflet are not drawn off-screen, so they don't have event handlers, so they wouldn't react as you would expect.

If you *really* want to emulate pointer events, do read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events and maybe even the source code for https://github.com/Leaflet/prosthetic-hand . I honestly believe that it's more hassle than it's worth for your use case.